# Appcelerator Tabgroup change to drop-down

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When in portrait tabgroup has a scrollbar to slide. but in landscape if length of all tabs over than width of screen. tabgroup is changing to drop-down

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var win3 = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var win4 = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var win5 = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var win6 = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var tab1 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title : 'aaaaaaaaaaa',
    window : win1
});
var tab2 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title : 'bbbbbbbbbbb',
    window : win2
});
var tab3 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title : 'ccccccccccc',
    window : win3
});
var tab4 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title : 'ddddddddddd',
    window : win4
});
var tab5 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title : 'eeeeeeeeeee',
    window : win5
});
var tab6 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title : 'fffffffffff',
    window : win6
});

var tabgroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
    tabs : [tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5,tab6]
});
tabgroup.open();
```

how to stop changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a default behavior of tab group. If you add more than five tabs, it will automatically add more tabs. You can't change this default behavior.

For more information, [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52).